# solve for product of primes with difference of squares of primes

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, linear-transformations, transformation

I had the following two algebras:

$$C(p,q) = \frac{p^2-q^2}{4} \quad \text{and} \quad N(p,q) = pq$$

where p and q are primes greater than 10, moreover, the number of integers(i.e. the length of each prime) are equal.

So for example, if $p = 101$, then $q$ has to be a prime with exactly three digits, like $139$.

Now, I would like to find a relation between  $C$ and $N$.

What I did is, I proved that $N(p,q) = pq$ is a one to one function due to the prime property and both $p$ and $q$ are greater than $10$.

Thus, if $N_{1} = N_{2}$, then $p_{1} = p_{2}, q_{1} = q_{2}$, which implies $C(p_{1}, q_{1}) = C(p_{2},q_{2})$.

Therefore, can I claim that there exist a one to one function that map $C$ to $N$?

If so, can I find a valid transformation or some formula to represent N with c?

If additional details are required, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any efforts!

Comment: You have not specified any ordering restriction on $p$ and $q$ relative to each other. Thus, note that if $p_1 \neq q_1$,  then if $N_1 = N_2$, you can conclude that in addition to $p_1 = p_2, q_1 = q_2$ you stated, it's also possible that $p_1 = q_2, q_1 = p_2$.

Comment: I can relate both of the functions, to goldbachs conjecture on a restricted sample space. It, doesn't proove anything though.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Hey John! Thanks for replying, the only restriction I could have on $p$ and $q$ is they do not equal to each other and I usually put $p>q$, btw, how did you get $p_{1} = q_{2}$ and  $q_{1} = p_{2}$ in addtion to the original statement?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Hey Roddy! That sounds interesting! Could you briefly show me about it?

Comment: @PetaGlz If $p \gt q$, then what I wrote doesn't apply. The reason it could apply without ordering is that when you factor $N_1$ to get $2$ prime factors, you can assign them in either order to $p_1$ and $q_1$. For example, $N = 15$ gives primes $3$ and $5$ as prime factors, allowing $(p,q)$ to be $(3,5)$ or $(5,3)$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Gotcha, thanks for the details!

Comment: $2m=p+q\implies p=m+d,q=m-d\implies pq=m^2-d^2; \frac{ p^2-q^2}{4}=md; $  told you it didn't prove anyrhing.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Gotcha, thanks for the effort